# Conditions on a Matrix to be infinitesimally stochastic/generator of a semi-group

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, markov-process

A matrix $(a_{ij})_{i,j=1,\dots,n} $ with real nonnegative entries is called (row-)stochastic iff the row sum is equal to one $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}=1$.

[We'll](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33230/matrices-whose-exponential-is-stochastic/) call a matrix $T$ an infinitesimally stochastic matrix iff the matrix exponential $exp(tT)$ is a stochastic matrix for all $t\geq 0$.

In general, are there characterizations on these kind of matrices?

In particular, for which numbers $t$ do we have that $$T(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
-t&t&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&-t&t&0&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\ddots &\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&\cdots&\cdots&0&-t&t\\
0&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

is an infinitesimally stochastic matrix. ($T=-tD + tJ$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with $1$s in the diagonal except in the last entry where it is zero and $J$ is a standard Jordan Block).

Numerically, this seems to be the case for a lot of $t$s, but I'm interested of the reason why this is the case. Maybe you can interpret $T$ as some kind of characteristic function for the multivariate multicnomial distribution that is represented by a stochastic matrix, but I'm also open for literature suggestions/other names for this kind of matrix.

Answer (score 3):

A stochastic matrix is a matrix $M$ with real nonnegative entries satisfying $M v = v$ where $v$ is the all-ones vector. If $A$ is infinitesimally stochastic then in particular

$$\exp (At) v = v$$

and differentiating with respect to $t$ gives $Av = 0$, so a necessary condition is that the row sums are all zero. Next we need a condition on $A$ guaranteeing that $\exp (At)$ has real nonnegative entries. It's necessary and sufficient for the off-diagonal entries of $A$ to be nonnegative; to see that this is sufficient use the limit

$$\exp (At) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{At}{n} \right)^n$$

and to see that it's necessary take $t$ to be small enough that $\exp (At) \approx 1 + At$.

Matrices with these properties are called [transition rate matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_rate_matrix), infinitesimal generators (of continuous-time Markov chains), or Q-matrices. In particular, the matrix you wrote is such a matrix.

Comment: I can't seem to follow your argument why a transition rate matrix (with rowsum = 0) is a infinitesimally stochastic one (withe the generator definition). Could you expand on the reason why we get from positity of the diagonal to the generator property?

Comment: @Roland: I don't quite understand your question. There are two parts here: one part involving row sums and one part involving nonnegativity. Which part are you asking about?

Comment: It's the nonnegative part, I'd appreciate some insight for. Also, it's worth noting that my matrix is only a Q-matrix if $t\geq 0$.

Comment: If the off-diagonal entries of $A$ are nonnegative, then all of the entries of $1 + \frac{At}{n}$ are nonnegative for $n$ sufficiently large (larger than the diagonal entries of $At$ in absolute value), hence so will the $n^{th}$ power of this matrix, hence so will the limit. Conversely, if $\exp(At)$ is stochastic for all $t \ge 0$, take $t$ to be very small so that $\exp(At) \approx 1 + At$; this matrix having nonnegative entries means the off-diagonal entries of $At$ are nonnegative also. (There's a bit more to say here about how small "very small" is but it's straightforward.)